# Refresh embed after 60 seconds for minecraft server util packages (discord.js v12)

Tags: node.js, discord.js, minecraft

So i tried to refresh embed every 60 seconds to see updated status of my minecraft server using [minecraft-server-util](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minecraft-server-util)

```
util.status('localhost', 25565, options)
        .then((response) =>{
            let online = response.players.online
            let max = response.players.max
            let motd = response.motd.clean
            let version = response.version.name
            let software = response.version.protocol

            if(version == 'Paper 1.16.5') version = 'Minecraft 1.16.5';

            const onlineEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#59ff59')
            .setTitle('Survival Server Status')
            .setDescription('Get Survival Server Status')
            .addFields(
                {name: 'Server Address', value: `localhost`, inline: true},
                {name: 'Online Players', value: `${online}/${max}`, inline: true},
                {name: 'Status', value: ':green_circle: Online', inline: true},
                {name: 'MOTD', value: `${motd}`, inline: true},
                {name: 'Version', value: `${version} `, inline: true}
            )
            .setTimestamp()
            message.channel.send(onlineEmbed).then(msg => {
                msg.delete({ timeout: 60000 }).then(msg => {
                    setInterval(() => {
                        msg.channel.send(onlineEmbed)
                    }, 60000)
                })
            })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                        .setColor('#d10000')
                        .setTitle('Survival Server Status')
                        .setDescription('Get Survival Server Status')
                        .addFields(
                            {name: 'Server Address', value: 'localhost', inline: true},
                            {name: 'Online Players', value: `None`, inline: true},
                            {name: 'Status', value: ':red_circle: Offline', inline: true},
                            {name: 'MOTD', value: `None`, inline: true},
                            {name: 'Version', value: `Minecraft 1.16.5`, inline: true}
                        )
                        .setTimestamp()).then(msg => {
                            msg.delete({ timeout: 60000 }).then(msg => {
                                setInterval(() => {
                                    msg.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                                    .setColor('#d10000')
                                    .setTitle('Survival Server Status')
                                    .setDescription('Get Survival Server Status')
                                    .addFields(
                                        {name: 'Server Address', value: 'localhost', inline: true},
                                        {name: 'Online Players', value: `None`, inline: true},
                                        {name: 'Status', value: ':red_circle: Offline', inline: true},
                                        {name: 'MOTD', value: `None`, inline: true},
                                        {name: 'Version', value: `Minecraft 1.16.5`, inline: true}
                                    )
                                    .setTimestamp())
                                })
                            })
                        })
        })
```

but instead of updating the status, it is sending a new message but using the old status. could anyone help me fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make this a function that returns the response outside the

```
util.status('localhost', 25565, options)
```

and then use the response to edit the message.

Now to edit the message it's pretty simple.

You can read [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60819093/discord-js-how-do-i-edit-message-embed-statements)

```
const loadEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#59ff59')
    .setTitle('Loading...')
var online
var max
var motd
var status
var plrcount
var version
var software
function update() {
    util.status('localhost', 25565, options)
        .then((response) =>{
            online = response.players.online
            max = response.players.max
            motd = response.motd.clean
            plrcount = `${online}/${max}`
            version = response.version.name
            software = response.version.protocol
            status = ":green_circle: Online"
            if(version == 'Paper 1.16.5') version = 'Minecraft 1.16.5';
        }).catch(error) => {
            plrcount = "None"
            motd = "None"
            version = "Minecraft 1.16.5"
            status = ":red_circle: Offline"
        })
}
let msg = message.channel.send(loadEmbed)
setInterval(() => {
    update()
    const onlineEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#59ff59')
        .setTitle('Survival Server Status')
        .setDescription('Get Survival Server Status')
        .addFields(
            {name: 'Server Address', value: `localhost`, inline: true},
            {name: 'Online Players', value: plrcount, inline: true},
            {name: 'Status', value: status, inline: true},
            {name: 'MOTD', value: motd, inline: true},
            {name: 'Version', value: version, inline: true}
        )
        .setTimestamp()
    msg.edit(onlineEmbed)
}, 60000)
```

N.B.: Loop the whole function or the whole setting of variables not just sending the message!!

Comment: Could you create the code of returns the response outside the util.status? cause i don't know how. Thank you

Comment: Here you go :) Have fun coding!

Comment: thank you so much, it's working. But there's some problem i can't use the (let msg = message.channel.send("`Loading...`")) without await, so now the message is edited but on top of the embed there's still "`Loading`" message

Comment: make the loading an embed if that helps (I edited the code so it should work now)

Comment: thank you so much, it works, you just need to put `let msg = await message.channel.send(loadembed)` :)